# vector multiplication, What does this $U_{1}$ come from, why can we just do that?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

Given that : $||u_{1}||= ||u_{2}|| = 1$, $ \langle u_1,u_2 \rangle = 0$ and P(x) =$ \langle x,u_1 \rangle \rangle u_1 + \langle x,u_2,\rangle  u_2$

Then I was confused by the following calculation, where does the $u_1$ come from ? how can we just turn $\langle x- \langle x,u_1 \rangle u_1 -\langle x,u_2 \rangle u_2,u_1 \rangle $ into $\langle x,u_1 \rangle -\langle \langle  x,u_1 \rangle u_1,u_1 \rangle -\langle \langle x,u_2 \rangle u_2,u_1 \rangle$?

\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
\langle x -P(x), u_1  & =\langle x- \langle x,u_1 \rangle u_1 - \langle x,u_2 \rangle u_2,u_1 \rangle \\
              & = \langle   x,u_1\rangle - \langle \langle x,u_1 \rangle u_1,u_1 \rangle - \langle \langle x,u_2 \rangle u_2,u_1 \rangle \\
              & = \langle x,u_1\rangle- \langle x,u_1 \rangle \langle u_1,u_1 \rangle - \langle x,u_2 \rangle \langle u_2,u_1\rangle\\
              & = \langle x,u_1 \rangle - \langle x,u_{1} \rangle  1 - \langle x,u_2 \rangle 0\\
              & =  0\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks for making the question legible.  Isn't your question really asking why, for fixed $a$, the map $x\mapsto\langle a,x\rangle$ is linear?

Comment: Expand the inner product using its linearity.

Comment: @kimchilover,  ok for a fixed a, the map x-> $\langle a, x \rangle$ is linear, that is because a is a scalar, but in this case,  we can just use $u_1$ ast scalar since ||$u_1$|| =1?

Comment: @momomo - No, $a$ is not a scalar. $\langle a,x\rangle$ denotes the inner product of the vectors $a$ and $x$; the result is a scalar. It has the properties $$\langle a,x+y\rangle=\langle a,x\rangle+\langle a,y\rangle$$ and $$\langle a+b,x\rangle=\langle a,x\rangle+\langle b,x\rangle.$$

Comment: @mr_e_man. ok now with your help, i see what happens here.  Thank you. but I will also accept  WindSoul explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The P(x) expression you have is a vector as a linear combination of vectors u1 and u2. Since the vectors u1 and u2 are perpendicular, P(x)=x. Therefore x-P(x)=0.

I have attached a handwritten solution.

[image]